# Inserting new column and values in excel worksheet c#

Tags: c#, excel, insert, worksheet-function

I am trying to append a new column to the beginning of an excel file and then add values to those cells, ( 1,2,3,4,5...) it will be used as my primary id for my database. I am having trouble trying to insert data into column, as much as I thought it would have been easy. Here is what I currently have:

```
private void cleanUpCollection(string file)
  {
      using (SpreadsheetDocument doc =
              SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false))
      {
          Worksheet worksheet =
              (Worksheet)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById("rId1");

          Range rng = worksheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);

          rng.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,
                                  XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);

          WorksheetPart worksheetpart =
                 (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById("rId1");
          foreach (var row in worksheetpart.Rows())
          {
             // My assumption was to go down each row and insert into the first column
          }
      }



  }
```

Any help on how to solve this problem would be very helpful! thank you!

Comment: Are you getting any error? Where have you stuck?

Comment: i was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sheetData = workSheet.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
Column firstColumn = sheetData.Elements<Column>().First();
var newCol = firstColumn.CloneNode(true) as Column;
firstColumn.InsertBeforeSelf<Column>(newCol);

foreach(Cell cell in newCol.Elements<Cell>())
{
    cell.Cellvalue = new CellValue(<Value>);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. It gives me an error in that row does not have the element "Elements<Cell>()" did you import any classes?

Comment: No it is present in the same namespace.